# Independence of sigma algebras through adding more r.v

Tags: independence

I have the following problem:
We have to sigma algebras $\sigma (u)$ and $\sigma (X_{i})$ which are not independent. $u$ and $X_{i}$ are random variables.

Now my question:
Why is it possible, in some cases, to find $X_{k}, X_{k+1} .....$ so that
$\sigma (u)$ is independent from  $\sigma (X_{i}, X_{k}, X_{k+1} .....)$.

The only thing I know is that the sigma Algebra $\sigma (X_{i}, X_{k}, X_{k+1} .....)$  would be finer than $\sigma (X_{i})$.

Comment: This is not possible. If $\sigma (X_{i}, X_{k}, X_{k+1} .....)$ is independent from $\sigma(u)$ then every sub sigma algebra must also be independent from $\sigma(u)$. In particular $\sigma (X_{i})$.

Comment: ah thanks! I was so confused